# get Title from video with youtube api v3 with javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to understand how the new data api from google works, more specifically the youtube (v3) one, but haven't been able to follow any of the google documentation successfully. If anybody could give me a quick example of how to get the title or any other metadata from a you tube video either using the video id or the video url, I will really appreciate it.

I have tried https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list but none of the requests seem to work for me.

Also tried following this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript

but as soon as I try gapi.client.setApiKey(YOUR API KEY); it starts giving me can't apply setApiKey to undefined etc etc

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If anybody wants to do this now their policies have changed so that you will be able to get data from your own channel more than others. Look that up before starting such a project.

Answer (score 1):

[Register your app first](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) and get a developer key, so you will your key there.

Comment: Thx,it was more a of loading issue though.